# What is the key combination for alphabet 'ज्ञ' on Hindi Bolnagari Key Board?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm using Hindi Bolnagari Key Board Layout. I'm not able to get the key combination for the alphabet <kbd>ज्ञ</kbd>. Please Help.

Comment: Please also expand your question and indicate if you are using iBus or SCIM or the default keyboard layout management methods. Also indicate what key combination you expect that letter to have.

Answer (score 6):

It is as per Sanskrit Varnamala (alphabets) rules -

- In "Bolnagri" -

  <kbd>ज (j)</kbd> +  <kbd>् (x)</kbd> + <kbd>ञ (Shift + y)</kbd> = <kbd>ज्ञ</kbd>
- In "Indian" (which is closer to "Mangal" in Windows which most of the professionals are used to) -

  <kbd>ज (p)</kbd> +  <kbd>् (d)</kbd> + <kbd>ञ (Shift + ])</kbd> = <kbd>ज्ञ</kbd>

Hope you already know -

<kbd>क (k)</kbd> +  <kbd>् (d)</kbd> + <kbd>ष (Shift + ,)</kbd> = <kbd>क्ष</kbd>

In "Bolnagri"

<kbd>क (k)</kbd> +  <kbd>् (d)</kbd> + <kbd>ष (Shift + s)</kbd> = <kbd>क्ष</kbd>